# like does not work for our URL

Tags: facebook-like

I have a problem with the likebutton. As soon as a user clicks the like-button the comment box appears for a (very) short time and then disappears again without giving the user the ability to like.
It is related to the URL the like button refers to. If I put another URL into the iframe it works. Why is it not possible to like our website (www.comex.eu)? Has anyone an idea?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Can you post some more code for that please? Hace you tried using the HTML5 implimentation

Answer (score 0):

Facebook sometimes prevents a Like from registering if it believes the site is likejacking / malicious etc. Or even if too many Likes are coming from a specific IP address. Give it some time (1-2 days) and it should start working (eventually).

Alternatively, try Liking the site using a different account or different IP address. But don't keep Liking / Disliking it or Facebook's system will think it's spam.